# Jquery ajax not post form with special characters in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying post whole form using jquery ajax. Here is my ajax call:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnadd').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("SaveUser", "UserMenu")",                       
                    data: $('#SaveUserForm').serialize(),                                           
                    datatype: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function(d) {
                        var r = JSON.parse(d);
                        if (r.Result === 'true') {
                            //Wohoo its valid data and processed.
                            alert('success');
                        } else {
                            alert('not success');                                
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                    }
                });             
        });
    });
```

It works nicely when I post the form without special character but If any field contain special character (Lets say, I have a text field password, that contain character <>) it does not trigger controller action result.
I have tired many solution regarding this problem but non of this work for me.

Here is my Controller `ActionResult` for receive ajax request:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SaveUser(AdminUserPanel model)
    {
      //some code for save into database
     return Json(new { Result = true });
    }
```

Do I need to change my Ajax function or any just extra setting(webconfig or other)?

Comment: Do your classes have any data annotations?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's debug console?

Comment: @Jasen There is no browser's console error

Comment: @nurdyguy Yes I do '[DisplayName("Password")]'
        '[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Password")]'
        '[DataType(DataType.Password)]' for password field which may contain special character.

Comment: BTW, you should not do `JSON.parse`. the object you get in the success callback is a js object. No need to parse it !

Comment: Your code should work fine even with special characters unless you have some data annotation using regex to prevent them. Are you getting some errors for your xhr call ? What is the response coming back ?

Comment: @Shyju Thanks for correcting me. But for no my main concern is all about form post with special character.

Comment: @Shyju I don't get any error. and data annotation for password are in the comment. I don't think that annotation for password is going to this problem

Comment: Its because ASP.NET thinks it's potentially dangerous text. Use `[AllowHtml]` attributes for specific fields or use `[ValidateInput(false)]` for whole action.

Comment: @Spectarion Thank you very much. It works. You saved my day. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Its because ASP.NET thinks it's potentially dangerous text.
Use [AllowHtml] attributes for specific fields

Example :

```
public class BlogEntry {
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    [AllowHtml] 
    public string BlogText {get;set;}
 }
```

or use [ValidateInput(false)] for whole action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult xyz(abc model)
{
///////////
}
```